# iOS ARKit setWorldOrigin has no effect

Tags: ios, arkit

I want to set my world origin to a reference point ARNode, this should be easy but has no effect.

```
// translate node
myNode.position = position;
// reset world origin to new node
[self.sceneView.session setWorldOrigin:(myNode.simdPivot)];

// Add the model to the scene
[self.sceneView.scene.rootNode addChildNode:myNode];
```

I switched on the debug functions but the world origin is not moving ... but also no crash or warning!?

```
self.sceneView.debugOptions = ARSCNDebugOptionShowWorldOrigin;
```

Can someone point me to the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I found that a matrix conversion is necessary to make it moving:

```
[self.sceneView.session setWorldOrigin:SCNMatrix4ToMat4(myNode.pivot)];
```

But still not exactly to the node point origin ... anyone who has an idea?